# Dimmer switches + outlet stopped working after vacuum caused a problem, breaker not tripped

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

I have a new tenant in my new home and one of the first things he did was plug in a vacuum that caused the lights in his room to go out.

I was able to restore power to half his room by flipping the breaker on and off, but the other half (one outlet and 2 3-way dimmer switches) just won't come on.

I've reset all the GFCI outlets I could find and taken a look at the wiring in the outlet, but now I'm at a loss as to what to do.

Any advice, or ideas what the problem could be?

Comment: It seems to me that there is likely a bad connection in the circuit.  The load (vacuum) that caused the breaker to trip also likely caused the poor connection to melt and separate.  The problem is likely in the last working outlet box in the circuit, or the non working one.

Comment: I've taken a look at the non-working outlet and I can't see anything obvious - what am I looking for? I also haven't looked at the last working one.

Comment: Check _all_ of the receptacles on that circuit - working or not, plug outlet, switch, or light.

Comment: Scorch marks, melted insulation on the wires, loose splices (may have to remove wirenuts to check the connection.

Are the wires wrapped around the screw terminals or stabbed into the back of the receptacles?  Back stabbed receptacles are notorious for poor connection issues.

Comment: The receptacles are NOT backstabbed. I don't know which circuit the outlet belongs to, but the one next to it is working (has 4 wires in the box), the broken onw which is not working has 2 wires in the box, and all of the other outlets/switches that *could* be on the circuit are working. Do I have to pull all my electric stuff out, or should I only bother with the ones close to/next to the outlet?

Comment: It is a trial and error process.  You will have to identify all the lights/switches/receptacles that are on the same breaker as the failed ones (and they may not all be in the same room), and then 'trace' the circuit by opening each device and identifying where the wires go until you find the problem.  There is also a chance (if there had been previous renovations) that there are hidden improper junction points, but start with the accessible stuff first.

Comment: I called an electrician, and for $278 he told me it was the smoke detector. Also, once it started to work, I found that the detector and those lights and that outlet are all on their own circuit that isn't connected to any of the breakers marked "lights", or even the lights main.